useNavigate() hook is not working , #React
I am trying to implement a registration page in my React application where, upon successful signup, the user should be redirected to the homepage. I am using react-router-dom for routing and react-query to handle API requests. However, the useNavigate hook is not working as expected and the redirection is not happening.
Here is my RegisterPage component:
Kindly help me out ;
import { json, Link, Navigate, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

import XSvg from "../../components/svgs/X";

import { MdOutlineMail } from "react-icons/md";
import { FaUser } from "react-icons/fa";
import { MdPassword } from "react-icons/md";
import { MdDriveFileRenameOutline } from "react-icons/md";
import { useMutation, useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";

const RegisterPage = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: "",
        username: "",
        fullName: "",
        password: "",
    });
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const {
        mutate: signup,
        isError,
        isPending,
        error,
    } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: async ({ email, username, fullName, password }) => {
            try {
                const res = await fetch("/api/v1/auth/signup", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ fullName, username, email, password }),
                });

                const resData = await res.json();
                if (resData.error)
                    throw new Error(resData.message || "Failed to create account");
            } catch (error) {
                throw error;
            }
        },
        onSuccess: () => {
            toast.success("Signed up successfully");
            navigate("/");   // HERE
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.error(error.message);
            toast.error(error.message);
        },
    });
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        signup(formData);
    };

    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    return (
        //react component
    );
};
export default RegisterPage;


